# Finding sum of a function u=n*x*y for n =[ 0 to N] ; x and y are some array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function, computation

I want to write a code using python for solving a function such as follows :

```
u = sum(n*x*y) for n=[0 to N]
```

Let's say x = [1,2,3,4,5] and y =[6,7,8,9,10] and n= [1,2,..100]

I expect an output like this :

u = [u0, u1, u2, u3..]; where u0 = sum([nn*x[0]*y[0] for nn in n]) and similarly for u1,u2..

Thought of doing this :

```
u = []
For i in n:
    j = sum([i*x*y])
    u.append(j)
```

Now of course the problem I have is idk how I can go about defining x and y in the loop. Probably need to use another for loop or while loop, or some if/else, but I'm not able to wrap my mind around it for some reason. Pretty new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean `sum( nn*(sum(xx*yy) for xx,yy in zip(x,y)) for nn in n )`?

Comment: Are you familiar with `numpy` or other numerical libraries? If you're doing a lot of math in Python, it's going to be an important part of it!

Comment: Can you please provide an explicit minimal numerical example? (input + output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
uu = sum( nn*(sum(xx*yy) for xx,yy in zip(x,y)) for nn in n )
```

which is similar but better than:

```
uu = sum( nn*(sum(x[i]*y[i]) for i in range(len(x))) for nn in n )
```

### FOLLOWUP

```
u = [sum([nn*xx*yy for nn in n]) for xx,yy in zip(x, y)]
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. I expect an out put like this : u = [u0, u1, u2, u3..]; where u0 = sum(nn*x[0]*y[0] for nn in n ) and similarly for u1,u2..

Answer (score 0):

Do you want:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [6,7,8,9,10]
n = [1,2,100]

u = [sum([nn*x[i]*y[i] for nn in n]) for i in range(len(x))]

# or
u = [sum([nn*x_i*y_i for nn in n]) for x_i, y_i in zip(x, y)]
```

Output:

```
[618, 1442, 2472, 3708, 5150]
```

[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) version:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
n = np.array([1,2,100])

u = ((x*y)*n[:,None]).sum(0)
```

Output:

```
array([ 618, 1442, 2472, 3708, 5150])
```